# SUMIFS with DATE criteria (match only year and month)

Tags: excel, date, sumifs

The data I am working with is daily, whereas the data I am importing values from is monthly.

I used SUMIFS and wanted to set criteria as YEAR & MONTH only. So that in the daily table, it returns the same value for 30/31 days of the corresponding month. 
It only returns 0's so far.

```
=SUMIFS('EA-04'!$D:$D,'EA-04'!$A:$A,DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2),1))/(DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2)+1,1)-DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2),1))
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I feel that the question is "How do I set criteria as YEAR & MONTH only. So that in the daily table, it returns the same value for 30/31 days of the corresponding month?"

Comment: Thank you @RichardBJ yes that's what I meant :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you can't change the format of each individual cell in the range that you want to interrogate but you can test if each date in that range falls within a certain date range ( greater than or less than)
So, if the value in cell A2 is the first of the month 1st October 2018 for example then you can use

```
=SUMIFS('EA-04'!$D:$D,'EA-04'!$A:$A,”>=”&$A2, 'EA-04'!$A:$A,”<”&EDATE($A2,1))
```

The formula says less than or equal to 1st October 2018 or less that 1st of November 2018

The EDATE(date,1) function adds 1 calendar month to the date in A2 so the 1st of the month becomes the first of the next month regardless of the number of days in the source month.

If the value in cell A2 is not the 1st then you can use this formula to change it to the 1st

```
=SUMIFS('EA-04'!$D:$D,'EA-04'!$A:$A,”>=”&$A2-(day($A2))+1, 'EA-04'!$A:$A,”<”&EDATE($A2-(day($A2))+1,1))
```

Comment: Hi! The value in A2 is 31/12/2001, the column it's in is daily. I tried both formulas you gave and it still returns 0.

Comment: I also tried setting the criteria as AND(MONTH($A2)=MONTH('EA-04'!$A2),YEAR($A2)=YEAR('EA-04'!$A2). but it also does not work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: 

The criteria range is monthly, with the day being last day of the month.

Comment: it should work as it's checking the whole month.  Check that the dates you have listed are stored in date format and not text.